# Error when copying column and pasting as value using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

It gives me the option to debug at the last line. I have just ended the macro and pasted value manually as the column has already been selected and copied.

Any insight as to what I have done wrong would be appreciated.

```
'copies data column and pastes as value to get rid of formula in blank cells

lo.ListColumns(8).DataBodyRange.Copy
lo.ListColumns(8).DataBodyRange.Select
lo.ListColumns(8).DataBodyRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=PasteValue
```

Comment: Why do you copy paste to the same range? Do you have formulas in there? If so, just saying range.value = range.value will do. No expensive copy-paste necessary. Formats should stay since it's the same range.

Comment: Yes, this is a part of a larger macro that inserts a formula for data validation. The formula gets inserted into blank cells and will either output a blank cell or the date for the item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `xlPasteValues` instead of `PasteValue`.

Though instead of copy/pasting, just do a value transfer:

```
With lo.ListColumns(8).DataBodyRange
    .Value = .Value
End With
```